# curious SIGKILL error

Tags: c++, sigkill

I am not getting a SIGKILL error on my machine, and neither on the ideone.com online compiler
Though it gives a SIGKILL on the spoj machine, cant figure out the reason
EDIT:
The program needs to use less than 256MB of data, presently it takes about 400MB
How do i minimise the memory usage, i am using only the elements either on the diagonal or below it in the array 'c'
Here is the code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define _ ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);
#define r 1000000007
using namespace std;
int c[10000][10000];
int main(){_
int i,j,t;
c[0][0]=1;
for(i=1;i<10000;i++){
    c[i][0]=1;
    c[i][i]=1;
    for(j=1;j<i;j++){
        c[i][j]=c[i-1][j]+c[i-1][j-1];
        if(c[i][j]>=r){
            c[i][j]-=r;
        }
    }
}
cin>>t;
for(int f=1;f<=t;f++){
   int n,k,a[10000],ans=0;
   cin>>n>>k;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>a[i];
   }
   sort(a,a+n);
   for(j=k-1;j<n;j++){
        ans+=((long long)a[j]*c[j][k-1])%r;
   }
   cout<<"Case #"<<f<<": "<<ans<<"\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: subsequent question : is that project euler ? bounty for anyone who retro engineers the problem # ? :)

Comment: Haha!Thomas! You are on the right track ;) but could you help me figure out where the error could be?

Comment: @Thomas: I suspect googling 1000000007 might be the way to go if you want to figure out the problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPOJ imposes a memory limit, and your 2D array appears to exceed that limit: [link](http://www.spoj.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=9851).

Comment: @user103260: How so? Are you saying `int` is one byte wide?

Comment: oh yeah sorry its 400 MB

Comment: So how do i minimise it then?because i am using only the lower diagonal elements of the 2d array

Comment: @user103260: Flattening a triangular matrix into a 1D array could be a pretty decent SO question in its own right (assuming it hasn't already been asked and answered).